# Adding a link in a related list

Tags: related-list

I have a related list of a junction object on one of my objects, and we removed the junction object name because the header was really long. Now, however, we don't have a way of clicking through to the junction object record. Is there a way to create a link next to the related list records, similar to Edit or Delete? We would need a View link.

Tia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a formula field. Choose "Text" type, then use the HYPERLINK function referencing the Id of the record : HYPERLINK("/" & Id, "View")

Just add the field to the related list. But it will take a column and i don't think it's possible to add a real link next to Edit/Delete

Comment: Thank you - that works well. Is it possible to say that I want to open the window in the current window without frames?

Comment: Default behavior open a new window. You can add "_top" parameter to the function in order to stay on the same window : HYPERLINK("/" & Id, "View","_top")

Answer (score -1):

What about just adding something like if using VF page :

```
<apex:column
    <apex:outputLink value="/{junctionObject.Id}">View</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Working on visualforce page but not in standard related list